# Generate big integers from strings using GMP

Tags: python, gmp

Is it possible to convert the following PHP code in Python?

```
return gmp_strval(gmp_init(substr(md5(mb_strtolower(preg_replace('/[^\w_-]+/u', '', trim($str)))), 0, 16), 16), 10);
```

What imports do I need?

Comment: I have no idea what any of those functions do, but since Python and PHP are both Turing-complete, I assume each one is capable of performing any computation that the other one can. So, to answer your question: yes.

Comment: Why do you need gmp? Python has (its own) built-in big int support with the `int` class.

Comment: i need to convert a string to a unique bigint like: test => 688887797400064883

Answer (score 4):

Yes:

```
>>> int('688887797400064883')
688887797400064883
```

No need to import anything.

Side note: This number you want to convert fits in a 64-bit integer. Although PHP is severely limited (only 32-bit numbers), Python will handle these and other arbitrarily long numbers for you just fine in the built-in `int` class (Python 2 would convert these to `long` objects, but automatically).